# Coordinating checking in the scoreboard

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm having some trouble solving a issue in my code, I hope you can help me.

I have two modules, `A` and `B`. Module `A` does requests to `B`, and after a number of cycles `B` sends a multi-cycle response to `A`. `A` can hold up to 8 requests waiting to be responded, and the responses from `B` don't necessarily come back ordered. That's why we use an ID, to identify the returning data.

To verify this behaviour, I have a scoreboard with several checkers. One of the checkings that I do is if the ID used for a request is free or not. To do that, I keep an associative array with the IDs pending to be responded, and I insert, check and delete items as needed. I control this from two interfaces and monitors, one for the requests and another one for the responses. The response monitor, being the responses more than one cycle long, waits until it has all the data to send a transaction to the scoreboard, where I update my structs.

The problem comes the moment that once that `A` sees that it is actually getting a valid response from `B`, frees the ID and can use it for a new request. That is happening in some of my simulations, and since I won't receive the transaction until all the response is complete, block `A` is doing a new request with an ID I won't know it's legit to use until I get the complete transaction from the monitor.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cycle that you see a response from B, why don't you move the request from A into another associative array, one that represents responses that have been initiated.  That way you'll have a free slot in original array to handle new requests from A, but now you'll have the new, second array to handle the multi-cycle responses that have already begun.

Comment: I'm not sure that would help. From the the scoreboard I only see the response once it is finished, when the monitor has been over the multiple cycles grabbing the response data, and only then I can do anything with it. So it is possible that the new request comes even a cycle or two before the response is notified...

Comment: It sounds like you will have to modify your test environment so that your scoreboard detects the start of a response from B.  That's going to be necessary if one of the conditions you want to check for is if the number of outstanding requests from A is never greater than 8. If you don't care about this check, then you can simply make your current array large enough to hold the max number of outstanding requests to verify that by the end of the test all requests have received responses.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I feared... I was trying to avoid that, but it seems that I will have to do quite a big change in the environment...

Comment: I will give you the response as valid, because in the end it's more or less what I did. Apart from the uvm_analysis_port I had for the complete transaction, I added another one that sends the ID at the beginning of the response, and using that one I move the requests from the pending_responses to the ongoing_responses. Thank you!